# Renomeando vários arquivos Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Eu tenho vários arquivos:

```
xaa.txt xab.txt xac.txt xad.txt até xcn.txt
```

preciso renomear todos os arquivos para:

```
nome1.txt nome2.txt nome3.txt etc...
```

Na ordem, ou seja, xaa.txt deve ser o nome1.txt o xab.txt deve ser o nome2.txt e assim por diante

É possível renomear pelo terminal de uma só vez?

Comment: Importa a ordem que vai ser renomeado?

Comment: Olá @FelipeAvelar, importa sim. o xaa.txt deve ser o nome1.txt o xab.txt deve ser o nome2.txt e assim por diante.

Comment: Sim, é possível.

vá no diretório onde os arquivos se encontram e execute o seguinte comando no terminal.

    var=$(ls -1 | sort -h); number=0; for i in $var; do mv $i nome_$number; number=$[number + 1]; done

explicação:

> var=$(ls -1 | sort -h)

 vai pegar todos os arquivos que tem no diretório em ordem alfabética.

> number=0

para começar a renomear a partir do 0.


> for i in $var; do mv $i nome_$number; number=$[number + 1]; done

Vai renomear com o nome desejado passando o numero da operação conforme a ordem alfabética, adicionando + 1 à variável $number.

Comment: @AlessandroSchneider! Funcionou! Obrigado!